# java.io.FileNotFoundException error

Tags: java, file-io, error-handling

I am trying to read a file and serialize it through the code below. However, I keep getting the file not found error. I have tried putting the file in the folder, on the desktop and creating a new file in eclipse itself. Please help.

Code:

```
public class Util implements Serializable {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            Automobile ford = new Automobile();
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(
                        "C:/Users/FName LName/Desktop/Data.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);
            String line = new String ();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream ("car.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream ("car.ser");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            int k=0;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
                String s = new String ();
                if (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    s = st.nextToken();
                }

                OptionSet list = new OptionSet ();
                int j = 0;
                while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String temp = st.nextToken();
                    String name = new String ();
                    int price = 0;
                    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer (temp);
                    while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        name = token.nextToken(",");
                        price = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken(","));
                        list.setOption(j,name,price);   
                    }
                    j++;
                }
                list.setName(s);
                ford.getOs().add(k, list);
                k++;
            }
            oos.writeObject(ford); 
            ford = (Automobile) ois.readObject(); 

            for(int i=0;i< ford.getOs().size();i++) {
                System.out.print(ford.getOs().get(i).getName()+":");
                for(int j=0;j<ford.getOs().get(i).getOpt().size();j++) {
                    System.out.print(ford.getOs().get(i).getOpt().get(j).getName() +
                            "," + ford.getOs().get(i).getOpt().get(j).getCost()+" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            ois.close();
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In future, please tag your question with the language you are using. This makes it so much quicker to get the help you need.

Comment: Are you sure about the folder names are spelled correctly?

Comment: It is not a good idea to print the error message "File not found" when you catch a ClassNotFoundException. The ClassNotFoundException means that an object from your ObjectInputStream cannot be read because the class has not been defined - it has nothing to do with not finding the file. Your claim that the problem got resolved when you changed the libraries hints at not the FileNotFoundException being a problem, but rather a ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try renaming the folder `FName LName` so it has no spaces? Spaces may be an issue. Also try it with backslashes (escaped with an additional `\`): `C:\\Users\\FName LName\\Desktop\\Data.txt`

Also check if you have permissions to that file. Try moving the file to the `C:\` and see if it's readable.

If none of that works, you can try to check if the JVM can see the file:

```
File f = new File(filePathString);
if(f.exists()) { /* do something */ }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The issue got solved by removing some external library which was stopping the program to run.

Comment: Forward slashes work just as well in Java. The suggestion about 'f.exists()' is pointless. The OP is likely to have even less access to C:\ as to the directory he is actually using. -1

Comment: @Izmaki and EJP, those were just suggestions for debugging the issue since OP seemed certain it was a file IO issue. I suggested eliminating spaces since some file systems require spaces to be escaped.

Comment: @Churro Really? Interesting - I did not know that. Which file systems require this?